# changing gem behaviour and packing it for deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have made minor modifications to mislav's famous will_paginate gem.  I would like to "pack" those changes along with the rest of the gems I have so I can deploy on other machines easily.  What I'm looking for is not a github commit as I only need those changes on my own app for my own purposes.

When I use "bundle pack" it indeed packs all my gems, but the original gem files that were downloaded and not the modifications i've made to the raw files.

How does one go about packing the current gems and then deploying them somewhere else along with changes made to them?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You say you are not looking for a github commit, but honestly I think that is the easiest way to do it.  Fork the repo, make the changes, commit and push to github and then add it to your Gemfile and point it to your fork.  Bundler can install the gem directly from github.  I don't even think you will have to regenerate the gemspec, as long as you are not adding new files.  In the Gemfile you do this:

```
gem 'will_paginate', :git=>'git://github.com/your_username_goes_here/will_paginate.git'
```

So in summary (in case you are not that familiar w/ github):

1. Login or sign up for github account.
2. Go to the will_paginate repo and click the "Fork" button
3. Copy the URL from your new fork
4. local_shell> git clone git://github.com/your_username_goes_here/will_paginate.git
5. Make your changes
6. local_shell> git commit -a
7. local_shell> git push
8. Add the git fork URL to your Gemfile
9. local_shell> bundle install

If you already have a github account, aside from making changes to the code, this whole process will probably take you about 2 minutes.  Easy and you will be able to keep track of what you have changed on github.  IMO its a bad idea to make changes locally and not commit them to a remote repo... things can get messy and confusing, especially if you are deploying these changes to prod.

Comment: Thanks!  I think just using a module_eval with an initializer file will work out for me for now.  I appreciate your contribution though!